# How to properly request a review for an app?

Tags: swiftui, storekit

I found the article below which seems to be what one should use to request a review of one's app:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/requesting_app_store_reviews

I implemented what's there, and it seems to work fine. However, I do get a warning in Xcode on the "await requestReview()" line:

```
@Environment(\.requestReview) private var requestReview


/// Presents the rating and review request view after a two-second delay.
private func presentReview() {
    Task {
        // Delay for two seconds to avoid interrupting the person using the app.
        try await Task.sleep(for: .seconds(2))
        await requestReview() // Warning here...
    }
}
```

The warning is:

> No async operations occur within the await expression

I understand it's technically because it's saying the requestReview() call isn't async, but this is apple code, so not sure if maybe there's a newer way to do this or what.

Note that I had to set the min version of the app to ios 16, it wouldn't work with 15 or older.

Answer (score 0):

The [`requestReview`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/environmentvalues/requestreview) in this demo code is async (or rather: it runs in `@MainActor` isolated context, hence `await`:

> @MainActor
>
> var requestReview: RequestReviewAction { get }

The one you are probably getting a warning about is [`requestReview`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/skstorereviewcontroller/2851536-requestreview), which is deprecated.

I'm not sure why your Xcode is getting confused. I tried with Xcode 15.2, and cannot reproduce this issue.

Comment: I don't get the "requestReview is deprecated". I don't get that from what I've read online. Everything I've read said that's how you're supposed to do it. Can you point to something that shows how you're actually supposed to do it?

Comment: @Jack which Xcode version are you using? I tested with 15.2

Comment: I'm using 15.3.